# Polite way of asking for a discount?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, politeness, culture

Suppose I want to buy something and I'm trading with a German person.
I want to drop the price a bit.
Is this usually done in German, and in what context?

Is “Gibt es einen Rabatt?” a good way of asking? If not, what are good ways to ask for a discount in German?

Comment: Without proper nitpicking and pointing out you are only tangentially interested in the product, it's unlikely someone gives you a discount. What's the reason you think you are eligible for a lower price than usual?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I am the buyer and I am asking for a discount.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What was it you put into G-translate?

Comment: A common German saying is "Kann man an dem Preis noch 'was machen?", although I don't like this expression.

Comment: One important thing to know would be: what is the concrete situation? What do you want to buy? What kind of transaction is this? In the supermarket? On a flee market? At a car dealership? In a Turkish grocery store? On Ebay? - All those place have different forms of behaviour, and different ways to communicate.

Comment: ***Erhalten** Sie einen Rabatt* in the situation you describe (you are the buyer) is so strange an expression that everybody will just be befuddled. If anything than the buyer would say ***Gewähren/geben** Sie Rabatt*? See answers below.

Comment: Just know, that asking for a discount is not usual in Germany, Austria and Switzerland. If you do it often, people might call you a *Schnorrer (moocher)*. Salespersons expect that you pay the price that they say. In their prices they do not calculate any margin for haggling.

Answer (score 9):

There was one answer by @Marzipanherz yesterday which strangely was deleted later on. He or she suggested quite correctly

> Können Sie mir beim Preis entgegenkommen?

Which is a good expression, as it can be used both in oral and written communication (as opposed to *Gewähren Sie Rabatt* and *Können wir am Preis noch was machen* which are solely usable in written vs. oral communication), and it is polite without being stilted.

Comment: Nothing mysterious here, I deleted it myself. Wasn't in the mood to discuss with a user who left a comment :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz    "Mysteriously" (for me) because it was a good answer. Or actually the best. All other expressions collected here are rather stilted or unnatural, or very casual.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "...which are solely usable in written vs oral communication"? Did you intend to say "which are solely usable in oral communication"? At least that's what I would think.

Answer (score 8):

To get a better price you could ask the seller:

> Gewähren Sie Rabatt[, wenn ich 10 Stück bestelle]?
>   *(Do you offer discount[ if I order 10 pieces]?)*

Or even more polite:

> Würden Sie Rabatt gewähren, wenn ich gleich 10 bestelle?
>   *(Would you give a discount if I order 10?)*

Comment: Was ist mit: "Gibt es vielleicht einen Rabatt, wenn ich 10 Stück davon bestelle?" oder "Können Sie mit dem Preis noch was runtergehen, wenn ich 10 Stück bestelle?", oder gar "wenn ich noch mehr davon bestelle, muss ich dann trotzdem den vollen Preis bezahlen?", usw.? "Gewähren" klingt im normalen Geschäft etwas geschwollen, m.E.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Klar, vollkommen in Ordnung, mach 'ne Antwort draus. Dann kannst du auch das mit einbauen: _»Krieg ich Rabatt, wenn ...«_ Würde ich auch nicht als unhöflich bezeichnen.

Comment: Ein wichtiger Unterschied zwischen "Gewähren Sie Rabatt" und "Können Sie mit dem Preis noch etwas runtergehen" ist, dass ersteres eigentlich nur für formale schriftliche Kommunikation, zweiteres eigentlich nur für informelle mündliche Kommunikation akzeptabel ist. Vertauscht man die Kommunikationssituationen, klingt man entweder gestelzt oder flegelhaft.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ja, _»gewähren«_ ist eher gehoben, ähnlich wie: _»Würden Sie mir Rabatt einräumen, wenn ...«_. Deplatziert, wenn du am Kiosk stehst und 20 Stangen Zigaretten brauchst.

Answer (score 4):

In such a situation, I would say something like:

> Gibt es vielleicht einen Rabatt, wenn ich 10 Stück davon bestelle?
>   Is there perhaps a rebate, if I order 10 pieces?

or

> Kriege ich vielleicht einen Rabatt, wenn ... etc. 
>   Can I get a rebate, if ...

or

> Können Sie mit dem Preis noch was runtergehen, wenn ich 10 Stück bestelle?
>   Can you go down with the price (a little), if I order 10 pieces?

or even

> Wenn ich noch mehr davon bestelle, muss ich dann trotzdem den vollen Preis bezahlen?
>   If I order more of those, do I still have to pay the full price?

I don't think words like "Preisnachlass" or "gewähren" are used a lot in daily life situations.

But if I want to ask such things politely, I often use *veilleicht* (*perhaps* or *maybe*) or Konjunktiv like *Könnten Sie ...* (*Could you ...*), *Würden Sie ...* (*Would you ...*), etc. or both:

> Könnte ich einen Rabatt bekommen, wenn...

Answer (score 4):

Germans usually don't ask for a discount that directly, we compare prices and directly go where it is cheapest. Or we say something like

"Im anderen Laden habe ich das billiger gesehen." (I've seen it cheaper somewhere else.)

and wait for the salesman to budge.

Answer (score 0):

From the customer's point of view:

I want to drop the price a bit. Do you offer a discount?

> Ich möchte den Preis etwas senken. Geben Sie einen Preisnachlass [Rabatt]?

From the salesman point of view:

Do you want a discount? I drop the price a bit.

> Möchten Sie einen Preisnachlass [Rabatt]? Ich senke den Preis etwas.

Comment: I don't think anyone says or even writes that, apart from *Geben Sie einen Preisnachlass, wenn ich in Bar bezahle?* which is the usual code for VAT fraud.